# Make loop draw for an amount of time in Processing

Tags: processing

I am trying to make the background of a sketch turn a different color for 2 seconds every 5 seconds but I don't know how. This is a simplified code of what I've got.

```
time = millis();
color GREEN = #1fa81f;

void setup(){
size(650, 800);
background(0);
}

void draw(){
circle(mouseX,mouseY,);

if (time > 500){
background(GREEN);
time = millis();
}
```

If someone could help me I'd really appreciate it. Thank you!!

Comment: Let's say you have 2 variables: `color1` and `color2` to switch between, just to avoid ambiguity: what 's the correct sequence: 1. after 5 seconds, `color1` toggles back forth  to `color2` and back at 2 seconds interval, then after 5 more seconds whatever the last color was stays on screen ? 2. after 5 seconds sketch turns `color2` from `color1`, stays as `color2` solid for 2 `seconds` then reverts to `color1` for the remainder of 3 seconds until the next 5 seconds trigger happens to repeat the `color1` to `color2` change ? (If you happen to have an animated gif of how you want to code post)

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```
int bgColor;
int lastColorChange;
int changeInterval = 5000; // 5 seconds
int colorChangeDuration = 2000; // 2 seconds

void setup() {
  size(400, 400);
  bgColor = color(random(255), random(255), random(255));
  lastColorChange = millis();
}

void draw() {
  background(bgColor);

  // Check if it's time to change the background color
  int elapsedTime = millis() - lastColorChange;
  if (elapsedTime >= changeInterval) {
    // Change the background color
    bgColor = color(random(255), random(255), random(255));
    lastColorChange = millis();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you so much for the piece of code. However, whenever I try to specifically make it toggle between two set colors and not random ones, it changes once and then stops working, stuck on the if loop color.

Maybe you know how to fix this?

Thanks again!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that swaps between 2 colors instead of randomizing the color -

```
color[] bgColor;
int colorValue = 0;
int lastColorChange;
int changeInterval = 5000; // 5 seconds
int colorChangeDuration = 2000; // 2 seconds

void setup() {
  size(400, 400);
  bgColor = new color[2]
  bgColor[0] = color(255, 0, 0);
  bgColor[1] = color(0, 255, 0);
  lastColorChange = millis();
}

void draw() {
  background(bgColor[colorValue % 2]);

  
  int elapsedTime = millis() - lastColorChange;
  if (elapsedTime >= changeInterval) {
    colorValue += 1;
    lastColorChange = millis();
  }
}
```